# Android where to save server TLS X509Certificate

Tags: android, ssl, certificate

I am tring connection to server o get the SSL ceriificate which I will need to reuse (for secure TCP connections in the app). I will need to pass the certificate in binary form to these classes and also I need if the user tries to reconnect to the same server the next day, compare this new cerificate to the saved one.
For this reason I have this code:

```
ttpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
inputStream = httpsURLConnection.getInputStream();
Certificate[] cert = httpsURLConnection.getServerCertificates();

//we are taking the last certificate which should be the server certificate  
X509Certificate x509Certificate = (X509Certificate) cert[cert.length-1];
byte [] encodedCertificate = x509Certificate.getEncoded();
```

I am wondering about the best and safest way to save this cerificate in order not to have to open the connection each time.

First I thought about using the Android KeyChain with help of this post:
http://nelenkov.blogspot.com.es/2011/11/using-ics-keychain-api.html.
The problem is his requires user interaction, and then the user has to activate a pattern or pin on his device otherwise this does not work. Another inconvenience is that the certificate will be available to all the apps and I don't want that.

I also tried using KeySore:

```
String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);

InputStream stream = null;
char[] password = null;
keyStore.load(stream, password);
if(keyStore.getCertificate(CERTIFICATE_ALIAS) == null){
    Log.d(TAG, "KeyStore doesn't contain field "+CERTIFICATE_ALIAS);
keyStore.setCertificateEntry(CERTIFICATE_ALIAS, certificate);
 } else {           
     Log.d(TAG, "KeyStore already contains field "+CERTIFICATE_ALIAS);
     }
 }
```

Each time I come back keyStore.getCertificate(CERTIFICATE_ALIAS) == null always returns true so it is no possible to "save" certificate this way.

I am considering saving the certificate to SharedPreferences using private mode of course but I am wondering if it is safe? If no is there a better way to save the certificate which will onl be used by my app (api level 14++)
 Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A certificate is public by design, so it doesn't really matter where you store them. A `KeyStore`  will work, but you have to call the `store` method to actually flush it to disk. If you need to connect to more than one server, it might be a good idea to use the SHA1 hash of the certificate subject name as the key, so you don't have to search through the whole keystore. If you use this approach, you can simply save the certificate(s) as a file(s) and use the filename as the key (ala Apache, Android also does this internally for trusted certificates).

If you import them into the system truststore (via `KeyChain`), certificate will be used as trust anchors system-wide, which may not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Using a KeyStore is a good solution. Use the [`Keystore.store(OutputStream, char[])`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyStore.html#store%28java.io.OutputStream,%20char%5B%5D%29) to 
save this keystore in the application persistent storage area (SD Card for instance) and reload the keystore every time the application starts.

With this keystore you will be able to create a SSLSocketFactory which only accept connections from a server using this certificate:

```
KeyStore ks = getKeystore();
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
tmf.init(ks);
TrustManager[] tms = tmf.getTrustManagers();
SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getDefault();
ctx.init(null, tms, null);
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(ctx.getSocketFactory());
```

Another solution is storing a SHA-1 or SHA-256 fingerprint of the certificate and comparing this fingerprint with the server certificate after the SSL handshake.

Comment: Unless all server certificates are self-signed, it might not be such a good idea to use them to initialize the `TrustManager`.

Comment: Yes, it is not a common practice. But AFAIK it is possible in the X509 cert path validation algorithm to consider a sub-CA as a trust anchor. Moreover if set up a Keystore for a unique usage and initialize it with the server certificate it is equivalent to a direct trust.

Comment: You can use anything as a trust anchor, but getting something of the net and blindly putting it in a trust store is simply a bad idea. If it's preinstalled or at least vetted by the user somehow it would be OK. Making sure you are connected to the same server doesn't buy you much if that server is compromised in the first place, but that's a problem with all TOFU schemes.